# Catch specific exception vs general exception

Tags: c#, vb.net

One of my co-worker asked what exception would I get if you execute a query that has a wrong table name. I was not able to answer since I always catch exceptions like the code below,

```
try
{
    ExecuteQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //show an error message
}
```

so I do not know what kind of error will be raised until it actually happens. But I like to code in this way because I can simply copy and paste that catch block at anywhere that needs to be try and catch blocked.

My question is that is it important to know what exceptions will be thrown and try to make as many specific catch exceptions as possible?

Comment: @fwan.. you can do a google search on Exception's and Exception type specifically do one on `SqlException` if you are using for example Sql Server.. I believe all exceptions are important but depends on what you want to report on in regards to ex.ToString() or ex.Message.. or some of the other properties you can get at.. stacktrace...etc.. [C# MSDN SqlException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Further from what Grant said, I would say that it is probably a good idea to think about whether you would want to catch any other exceptions and handle them differently. Do you want to handle a null pointer exception the same as a custom exception or a file access error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is that is it important to know what exceptions will be
>   thrown and try to make as many specific catch exceptions as possible?

It depends. If you are going to catch and handle specific exception then it makes sense to catch specific exception first and then the base exception.

One example could be to determine insertion of duplicate primary key, where you want the user to enter different value since the table can't allow insertion of duplicate key. In that case you will catch `SqlException` first and then have another block of `Exception` to catch any other.

```
try
{
    ExecuteQuery();
}
catch (SqlException sqlException)
{
    if (sqlException.Number == 2627) //duplicate key
    {
        // ask user to enter new value, repeat `ExecuteQuery`
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //show an error message
}
```

Without catching `SqlException`  you will not have access to `Number` field which has details about the particular `SqlException`.

*(by the way, the above code is just an example to catch and handle specific exception, insertion of duplicate key can be avoided by checking the value first in table)*.

Comment: "Without catching `SqlException` you will not have access to Number field" <- That is incorrect.  Since a `SqlException` *is* an `Exception`, the `Exception` you catch is of type `SqlException` and you have access to all of `SqlException`'s custom properties.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. But generally, it is good to catch specific exceptions if you wish your application to behave differently under different circumstances. For example, a `FileNotFoundException` could tell you that your user needs to verify a path. General `catch` blocks are useful at the highest level of your application, but getting more specific further down the line allows you better control over how to respond to specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is important if you want to show some personalized message about the exception to the user. For example: if it is a NullException, it shows a message with some code, for example 5504. And this number he/she says to helpdesk to inform about the problem. An article about this is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154121/Using-Try-Catch-Finally)

Comment: But when I use the general exception, it tells me what kind of error was raised such as IndexOutOfRange, NullReferenceException, etc so the user could tell me the error message and I will know what happened.

Comment: Yes, I know. But think like the user. Imagine he/she is calling to another person beyond you. And imagine the user seeing in the screen the message "...IndexOutOfBoundsException...". This is nothing user friendly